# What should be the contentType when i send ASP .NET complaint dictionary to server

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My client sends following information to the server.

```
var receiptObj = {
    Amount: tx_amount,
    Comment: ''+tx_comment+'',
    Filename: ''+filename+'',
    Image: ''+result+''
}
data = {authToken: sessionStorage["authToken"], receipt:receiptObj};
```

I convert the data into a format that ASP .NET server understands as ..

```
var dataToSend = $.toDictionary(data);
```

Can some one help me to know what should be the contentType now?
When i convert the above data and post via REST client or Poster tool , server is rejecting the data.

**EDIT:**
Data looks as below

```
[{ "name": "authToken", "value": "ftdiQ/8QXH"},{ "name": "receipt.Amount", "value": "10.00" },{ "name": "receipt.Comment", "value": "test cancel" },{ "name":"receipt.Filename", "value": "test.jpg" },{ "name": "receipt.Image", "value": ""}]
```

Comment: That depends only on what `$.toDictionary()` returns. It's hard to say without seeing the implementation of `.toDictionary()`, could you please add that? Maybe you could add the value of `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like JSON to me. JSON's MIME type is `application/json`.